# div stretching to specified width

Tags: html, css, width

Im trying to create a 2 page column, but my divs don't stretch to the width I specify and I don't get why. I have linked the jsfiddle for my code.

code here:

```css
.container{
 width: 960px;
 background-color: grey;
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.column1{
 background-color: red;
 display: inline;
 width: 480px;
}

.column2{
  width: 480px;
 background-color: yellow;
 display: inline;

}
```

```html
  <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="column1">a</div>
    <div class="column2">b</div> 
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: try inline-block instead of inline

Comment: Instead of trying to sidestep the SO rule of posting a code example **in your question** by highlighting meaning words as code, why not just do as you're asked? You saw the big, red warning box but chose to ignore it instead. Why?

Comment: change the display property to block and float the both the divs to left..https://jsfiddle.net/atsnoe7z/4/

Comment: @Paulie_D you are correct. I apologize, i'm still quite new to stack. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to create 2 `<div>` elements that are placed on the left and right side of the page? If so, this should solve your problem:

```css
.container{
  width: 960px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.column1{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.column2{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column1">a</div>
    <div class="column2">b</div> 
  </div>
</body>
```